# Submit form with radio buttons generated from an array

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button, form-fields

I have a list of radio buttons for guests to select whether they're attending an event or not.

A `party` can have several members, so multiple yes/no options can exist on the same page.

Idea is that a person can go down the list and hit yes or no on guest attendance. I am then trying to segment out the names of those who have accepted and declined into `arrays`, so I can push it to `wpdb`.

I have the following that generated the radio options:

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $result) { 
    $party = $result['party']; // "John, Doe" in DB varchar 
    $party_guests = explode(",", $party);

    $attending_array = array();
    $not_attending_array = array();
  
    foreach ($party_guests as $index => $guest){
        ?>
        <span class="guest__name"><?php echo $guest; ?></span>
        <div class="guest__options-option">
            <span>Attending?</span>
            <div class="guest__options-group">
                <input class="guest__attendance-input" id="attending_array[<?php echo $index; ?>]" type="radio" name="attending-<?php echo $index; ?>" value="<?php echo $guest; ?>" required/>
                <label for="attending-yes-<?php echo $index; ?>">Yes</label>
            </div>
            <div class="guest__options-group">
                <input class="guest__attendance-input" id="attending_array[<?php echo $index; ?>]" type="radio"  name="attending-<?php echo $index; ?>" value="<?php echo $guest; ?>" required/>
                <label for="attending-no-<?php echo $index; ?>">No</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

But I cannot see a way in which I can (via `PHP`) dynamically add the names to the `attending_array` or `not_ attending_array`?

How can I do an `array_push` based on what option the user clicks on? I cannot target a specific `name` because `$party` may contain 2 guest, 6 guest etc.

Comment: Looks like you have your `id` and `name` naming convention reversed.  Because `for` and `id` are related, you will want to use integer-suffixes for those.  Because you want to submit an array of attendance selections, you want to use array syntax with the `name` attributes.  Within a normal form submission, only the fields with `name` attributes will be in the payload and they will be keyed by the `name` attribute. Shall we close this question as a typo question?  You know what to do, you just accidentally did it in reverse.

Comment: Of course, you cannot populate those two php variables with user selections because PHP is finished running before the user will even see the output.  You'll need to use javascript or a form submission to receive those selections and then you can populate those PHP variables.  Alternatively, you can populate javascript variables using the user's selections (without triggering a server-side process).  It seems you have a fundamental flaw in your understanding of client-side/server-side processes.